# What is the logarithm of $(a-b)\delta_{ij}+b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Just now I came across the expression similar to:

$x_{ij} = (a-b)\delta_{ij}+b$

The author then somehow converts this expression, into:

$\ln x_{ij} = (\ln a-\ln b)\delta_{ij}+\ln b$

This comes completely out of the blue for me since after taking logarithms on both sides, I would have never simplified R.H.S. $\ln [(a-b)\delta_{ij}+b]$ to the expression given above since the logarithm of a sum is not a sum of the individual logarithms in general.

What is the justification of what author did? Does that Kronecker delta have some magic property which allows this? If I put $1$ or $0$ for Kronecker delta, I do get correct values of $x_{ij}$ which probably means that what author has done is actually right. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a property of Kronecker delta.

If it helps, let's rewrite $x_{ij}$.

$$x_{ij}=\begin{cases} a, & \delta_{ij}=1 \\ b, & \delta_{ij}=0\end{cases}$$
Hence, 
$$\log x_{ij}=\begin{cases} \log a, & \delta_{ij}=1 \\ \log b, & \delta_{ij}=0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that the author simply rewrote the case-wise solution.  The only "magical property of Kronecker deltas" at work here is that the function
$$
f_{ij} = \begin{cases}
p & i=j\\
q & i \neq j
\end{cases}
$$
can always be rewritten as $f_{ij} = (p-q)\delta_{ij} + q$.

Moreover, then, this means that for any function $g(x)$, we have
$$
g(f_{ij}) = \begin{cases}
g(p) & i=j\\
g(q) & i \neq j
\end{cases} = (g(p) - g(q))\delta_{ij} + g(q)
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $i\neq j$, then $$(\ln(a)-\ln(b))\delta_{ij}+\ln(b)=\ln(b)=\ln((a-b)\delta_{ij}+b).$$
If $i=j$,
$x_{ij}=(a-b)\delta_{ij}+b=a-b+b=a$, and $$(\ln(a)-\ln(b))\delta_{ij}+\ln(b)=\ln(a)-\ln(b)+\ln(b)=\ln(a).$$
The claim follow.